Download records from large avro file on azure storage
I want to download records from an avro file that is sitting on an Azure Gen2 storage account. The file itself is too large to handle locally.
The current approach is defined by the following Python pseudo-code
from io import BytesIO
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumReader
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

storage_stream = file_client.download_file()
bytes = storage_stream.readall()
stream = BytesIO(bytes)
reader= DataFileReader(stream, DatumReader())

The readall() creates memory issues, as the whole file is read to memory. Any suggestions on how I could modify and improve the setup to stream record by record from the avro file?


Download records from large avro file on azure storage

You can use the below code to read the larger avro file from azure storage using fastavro library.
Code:
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from fastavro import reader
from io import BytesIO

connection_string = "xxxxxxxx"
file_system_name = "test"
file_name = "large_avro_file.avro"

datalake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
file_client = datalake_service_client.get_file_client(file_system_name, file_name)

try:
    # Create a streaming reader for the Avro file
    downloaded_file = file_client.download_file()  

    with BytesIO() as stream:
        for chunk in downloaded_file.chunks():
            stream.write(chunk)
        stream.seek(0)  
        avro_reader = reader(stream)
        for record in avro_reader:
            print(record)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

The above code creates a streaming reader for the Avro file. It then reads the Avro file record by record and prints each record. The file is downloaded in chunks and written to a BytesIO stream before being read by the Avro reader.
Output:
{'id': 999989, 'name': 'Name 999989', 'description': 'Description 999989'}
{'id': 999990, 'name': 'Name 999990', 'description': 'Description 999990'}
{'id': 999991, 'name': 'Name 999991', 'description': 'Description 999991'}
{'id': 999992, 'name': 'Name 999992', 'description': 'Description 999992'}
{'id': 999993, 'name': 'Name 999993', 'description': 'Description 999993'}
{'id': 999994, 'name': 'Name 999994', 'description': 'Description 999994'}
{'id': 999995, 'name': 'Name 999995', 'description': 'Description 999995'}
{'id': 999996, 'name': 'Name 999996', 'description': 'Description 999996'}
{'id': 999997, 'name': 'Name 999997', 'description': 'Description 999997'}
{'id': 999998, 'name': 'Name 999998', 'description': 'Description 999998'}
{'id': 999999, 'name': 'Name 999999', 'description': 'Description 999999'}



Although this code is functional, it does not solve the main issue which is that the BytesIO object stream is too large to fit in memory. I guess an avro reader that could take a StorageStreamDownloader as input to download record by record would be ideal.
